# compound interest calculation in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to calc a compound interest with different deposits per year.

My Problem is that the interest is not correct as of 2018 and later.
The interest is without the previous sum of interest+balance.
I think I need to calc this in the recursive part but I dont know how to get the previous value.
I have tried something with Lag but i am not sure if it works with recursive

https://dbfiddle.uk/AzUqXumD

Also the next step would be the calculate this until 2063 with a deposit growth of 3%

From fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE "maintable" 
(
    "id"    int4,
    "myyear"    numeric,
    "deposit"   numeric
);
INSERT INTO "maintable" ("id", "myyear", "deposit") VALUES
    ('1', '2016', '1260'),
    ('2', '2017', '1428'),
    ('3', '2018', '1904'),
    ('4', '2019', '2100'),
    ('5', '2020', '2191'),
    ('6', '2021', '2226');

WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS (
  SELECT mt.myyear, 
  mt.deposit as deposit,
  4 as intrate,
  0.0 as interest,
  0.0 as interest_prev,
  0.0 as deposit_prev,
  mt.deposit as balance_new,
  0.0 as balance_prev,
  0.0 as a
  FROM maintable mt 
  WHERE mt.myyear= (SELECT MIN(mt.myyear) FROM maintable mt )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
  mt.myyear, 
  mt.deposit, 
  4, 
  interest+999 as interest,
  interest_prev,
  deposit_prev,
  mt.deposit+balance_new as balance_new,
  balance_prev,
  LAG( CTE.deposit,1) OVER (ORDER BY CTE.myyear asc) as a
  FROM maintable mt 
  JOIN CTE ON mt.myyear = CTE.myyear +1
)
select 
  myyear, 
deposit,
 intrate,
  case 
  when ( ROUND(CAST(LAG( balance_new,1) OVER (ORDER BY myyear asc) AS numeric), 2))*0.04  is null then 0
  else (ROUND(CAST(LAG( balance_new,1) OVER (ORDER BY myyear asc) AS numeric), 2))*0.04
  end AS interest,
  case 
    when balance_new+ ROUND(CAST(LAG( balance_new,1) OVER (ORDER BY myyear asc) AS numeric), 2)*0.04  is null then deposit 
  else  balance_new+ ROUND(CAST(LAG( balance_new,1) OVER (ORDER BY myyear asc) AS numeric), 2)*0.04
  end as balance_new,
    case 
    when ROUND(CAST(LAG( balance_new,1) OVER (ORDER BY myyear asc) AS numeric), 2) is null then 0 
  else   ROUND(CAST(LAG( balance_new,1) OVER (ORDER BY myyear asc) AS numeric), 2)
  end as balance_prev,
  a
FROM CTE
```

This is the desired result table:

```
myyear  deposit intrate balance   interest
2016    1260    4       1.260        0
2017    1428    4       2.738        50
2018    1904    4       4.752        110
2019    2100    4       7.042        190
2020    2191    4       9.515        282
2021    2226    4       12.121       381
```

Comment: Just a heads up, I brought through relevant sql from your fiddle (thank you for supply the fiddle, that is a huge help). Bring the code through to the question ensures that even if the link fails at some point in the future, the important parts are preserved (if someone stumbles upon this question later on).

Comment: Would it be possible to provide us with desired results from this sample data as well?

Comment: Hi, I have added the desired results table in this post as well